# How to show all files from directory Laravel

Tags: laravel

How to show all files form directory in view

[image: This my files]

Comment: You can write some rules in .htaccess file.

Comment: This documentation may help you https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Storage facade

```
$directory = 'name of a directory';
            // relative to root config set in config/filesystems.php which 
             by default is "storage_path('app/public')" so the search 
             will be in this directory

$directories = Storage::directories($directory);
// Recursive...
$directories = Storage::allDirectories($directory);
```

Then you have the list as an array pass it 
to view

```
 return view('view path',compact('directories'));
```

Comment: can u explain more? i want to show those files in my view how sir ?